# How to print a list of function values from a generating function in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and just starting to learn the basics.

I have defined a function recursively and I want to print a list of function outputs.

This is the code:

```
def x(n):
    assert n>=0, "Only non-negative integers n are allowed"

    if n == 0:
        return 5
    else:
        return (x(n-1)+5)/x(n-1)

print([x(0),x(1),x(2)])


for k in range(0,9,1):
    print(x(k))
```

So my question is: say I want to print a list of the first 10 outputs of the sequence/function, i.e. x(0),...,x(9), how do I do this without actually listing each output manually? I want them to be in the form "[x(0),...,x(9)]", just like I did for the first 3 values. My attempt is in the last command of the program, where k moves from 0 to 9. The last command clearly prints the first 10 outputs, but not as a list, i.e. in [] brackets.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

***One Solution:***

I replaced the code

```
for k in range(0,9,1):
    print(x(k))
```

with

```
print([x(k) for k in range(9)])
```

This puts the outputs in a list, i.e. in the [ ] brackets. Worked wonderfully!

Comment: `results = [x(k) for k in range(9)]`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it could be that easy! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: The magic of python lol

Comment: Off-topic note: `range(0,9,1)` can be simplified to `range(10)` in the code you provided.

Comment: @asikorski Oh yes, I tried this and it's true. Very handy when trying to keep your code as minimal as possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
print([x(n) for n in range(9)])
# outputs: [5, 2.0, 3.5, 2.4285714285714284, 3.058823529411765, 2.634615384615384, 2.8978102189781025, 2.72544080604534, 2.83456561922366]
```

**Explanation:**

We're making a list out by calling the function `x()` for each of the numbers (`n`) that are in the range from 0 to 9 (not included).

Please note that it is implicit that the starting point of the `range()` function is 0, that the step is 1, and the endpoint (9) is not included.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Very simple but effective, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for a beginner (not an one-liner, should be easier to understand):

```
myarray = []

for i in range(9):
  myarray.append(x(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the alternative to a list comprehension using `map`, since this is practically the scenario that `map` was made for:

```
xs = map(x, range(9))
```

`map` takes a function, and applies it to each member of the supplied iterable.

The main difference between this and using a comprehension is this returns a lazy iterable (a `map` object), *not* a list. `x` will not be applied to an element until you request the element.

Use of a list comprehension/generator expression is preferable in the majority of scenarios, but `map` is nice if you need/can tolerate a lazy result, and you already have a predefined function.